# Can't write to an Intel 750 series PCIe SSD in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, ssd, centos, pci-express, centos-7

I am attempting to install an Intel 750 series 400 GB PCIe SSD card into a CentOS 7 system.

The SSD shows up as `/dev/nvme0` and `/dev/nvme0n1`

Attempting to format it with `fdisk /dev/nvme0n1` results in:

```
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

Error closing file
```

After attempting to format it `dmesg` contains:

```
[ 4978.018955] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1, logical block 0
[ 4978.019007] lost page write due to I/O error on nvme0n1
[ 4978.019908]  nvme0n1: unknown partition table
```

Attempting to write to it with dd results in:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=1M oflag=direct
dd: error writing ‘/dev/nvme0n1’: Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 30.0685 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

What steps should I attempt next to debug the cause of the SSD failing to write?

`isdct show -intelssd 1` results in:

```
ls: cannot access /dev/sg*: No such file or directory
- IntelSSD CVCQ513200P2400AGN -
DeviceStatus: Healthy
Firmware: 8EV10135
FirmwareUpdateAvailable: Firmware is up to date as of this tool release.
ModelNumber: INTEL SSDPEDMW400G4
ProductFamily: Intel SSD 750 Series
SerialNumber: CVCQ513200P2400AGN
Index: 1
DevicePath: /dev/nvme1n1
Bootloader: 8B1B012E
```

The only LED on the card that is lit is green.

`uname -r` results in:

```
3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to update your kernel to >=3.19.

See [this post](https://communities.intel.com/thread/62865) from the Intel Community forum